# How to call a modal service in an app with a route provider?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have read many tutorials about creating simple modals using angular bootstrap.  However, all of the examples seem to be based in single page apps that do not use route provider or other more complex architectural patterns.  **What specific changes need to be made to [the code in this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NKYaVBLLwrdsTzK1I9Po?p=preview) to enable a modal service to be called through a controller in an app that uses route provider?**

The example in the plnkr link above is an app that has:
1.) a route provider with two routes, `/` and `/public1`.
2.) A `navigation` controller handles the table of contents, and thus sits above any/both routes.
3.) A `modalService` is injected into the `navigation` controller.
4.) And `index.html` contains a div with the table of contents that is managed by the `navigation` controller.  A button inside the navigation div in `index.html` calls the `deleteCustomer()` method of the controller, which should then cause a modal to appear.  **What changes need to be made in order for the modal to appear when the button is clicked?**

On my devbox, the FireFox debugger is generating the following compilation error when I try to launch the app:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module hello due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module navigation due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module modalService due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'modalService' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/nomod?p0=modalService
minErr/<@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:12
module/<@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:2015:1
ensure@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1939:38
module@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:2013:1
loadModules/<@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4503:22
forEach@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:321:11
loadModules@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4
```

**When I download the plnkr as a zip then unzip it and debug in my devbox browser, the FireFox debugger says that it is not able to instantiate the `hello` module, which is the root of the plnkr app.** The plnkr app thus should be able to recreate the problem as soon as we figure out the simple problem of getting the main module for the app to load.  (A comment explaining how would be appreciated.).

---

**THE CODE:**

---

Though the complete code is in the plnkr at the link above, I will also copy sections of the code as follows:

`index.html` is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <base href="/" />
    <link data-require="ui-bootstrap@0.13.1" data-semver="0.13.1" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@0.13.1" data-semver="0.13.1" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.1/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.js" data-semver="1.5.0" data-require="angularjs@1.5.0"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="hello" ng-cloak class="ng-cloak">
    <!-- start of content section -->
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

    <div ng-controller="navigation" class="container">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist"  >
            <li><a class="label label-success" href="/">Home</a></li>
              <li><a class="label label-success" href="/public1">public1</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- modal test follows -->
            <p><a href class="btn btn-default btn-lg " ng-click="deleteCustomer()">Click to Delete Customer</a></p>
          <!-- end of modal test -->
    </div>

    <div class="container">
    <div ng-view=""></div>
    </div>

    <!-- end of content section -->    

    <!-- begin local build files -->
    <!-- <script src="script.js"></script> -->
    <script src="modalService.js"></script>
    <script src="home.js"></script>
    <script src="public1.js"></script>
    <script src="navigation.js"></script>
    <!-- end local build files -->

  </body>

</html>
```

`script.js` is:

```
'use strict';

/** * Main module of the application. */
angular
  .module('hello', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngTouch', 'home', 'public1', 'navigation' 
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'home.html',
        controller : 'home',
        controllerAs: 'home'
    })
    .when('/public1', {
        templateUrl : 'public1.html',
        controller : 'public1',
        controllerAs: 'public1'
    })
    .otherwise('/');

    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

  })
.run([ function() {

}]);
```

`navigation.js` is:

```
'use strict';

angular
.module('navigation', ['modalService', 'ngRoute'])
.controller('navigation', function($scope, modalService, $route) {

    $scope.tab = function(route) {
        return $route.current && route === $route.current.controller;
    };

    $scope.deleteCustomer = function () {

        var custName = 'Some Random Person';

        var modalOptions = {
            closeButtonText: 'Cancel',
            actionButtonText: 'Delete Customer',
            headerText: 'Delete ' + custName + '?',
            bodyText: 'Are you sure you want to delete this customer?'
        };

        modalService.showModal({}, modalOptions).then(function (result) {
            //some code will go here.  But for now can we just
            //get the modal to appear and for the cancel button to work?
        });
    }

});
```

And `modalService.js` is:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('modalService').service('modalService', ['$modal',
    function ($modal) {

        var modalDefaults = {
            backdrop: true,
            keyboard: true,
            modalFade: true,
            templateUrl: 'modalContent.html'
        };

        var modalOptions = {
            closeButtonText: 'Close',
            actionButtonText: 'OK',
            headerText: 'Proceed?',
            bodyText: 'Perform this action?'
        };

        this.showModal = function (customModalDefaults, customModalOptions) {
            if (!customModalDefaults) customModalDefaults = {};
            customModalDefaults.backdrop = 'static';
            return this.show(customModalDefaults, customModalOptions);
        };

        this.show = function (customModalDefaults, customModalOptions) {
            //Create temp objects to work with since we're in a singleton service
            var tempModalDefaults = {};
            var tempModalOptions = {};

            //Map angular-ui modal custom defaults to modal defaults defined in service
            angular.extend(tempModalDefaults, modalDefaults, customModalDefaults);

            //Map modal.html $scope custom properties to defaults defined in service
            angular.extend(tempModalOptions, modalOptions, customModalOptions);

            if (!tempModalDefaults.controller) {
                tempModalDefaults.controller = function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
                    $scope.modalOptions = tempModalOptions;
                    $scope.modalOptions.ok = function (result) {
                        $modalInstance.close(result);
                    };
                    $scope.modalOptions.close = function (result) {
                        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                    };
                }
            }

            return $modal.open(tempModalDefaults).result;
        };

    }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see below, happy coding ! :)

In plunker you can set `<base href="/" />`, you have to script that:

```
<script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
</script>
```

You forgot some script required by ui-bootstrap :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular-touch.js"></script>
```

And you forgot to load ui.bootstrap in your module :

```
angular.module('modalService', ['ui.bootstrap']).service('modalService', ['$modal', function(){...})
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/4BiF2SlhOZDrFgMzj31z?p=preview

Comment: When you say "my local devbox is not letting javascript/angular compile", are you talking about concatenation/uglify task ?.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this.  The resolution to the problem came from removing the bower-generated dependencies and replacing them with the http-linked-dependencies in your working plnkr.  This means that I have to research how to define bower dependencies for these libraries.  I am marking yours as the accepted answer because looking up the bower dependencies might be a separate question if I hit a roadblock when I have time to do that later.  Thank you again.

Comment: You're wellcome mate :)